# Programmatically change height of the window more than the height of the screen in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, windows, macos, cocoa, applescript

Respected low-level users of Mac OS, please, help.

I'm trying programmatically to change height of window of safari (*or other window*). I'm was trying used AppleScript and `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue` of Carbon, but none of these methods can't increase the window bigger than the height of the screen. But, the width changes without any problems.

I guess I'd be starting with something like `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING` flag under Win32.

Maybe, you can disable this functionality, which monitors the size of the window or completely shutdown the one who is responsible for it?

Note that I want to do this programmatically from an external process - I'm not asking how to control just my own app's window size and position.

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, in such a powerful operating system as Mac, this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, search for "Note that any NSWindow with a title bar automatically constrains itself to the screen" in the [Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SizingPlacingWindows.html).

Comment: Maybe, can disable this functionality, which monitors the size of the window or completely shutdown the one who is responsible for it?

Comment: No, the method constrainFrameRect:toScreen: is called by default by the framework to adjust the height of the window to fit within the screen: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html. You could override it but, obviously, in your applications.

Comment: But it is characteristic only of the window of *my* application, but I need to change the height of *another* window of an *other* applications. In any case, no?

Comment: I wanted to mean: for a window of an application of your (developed by you) you can override the method and obtain what you want; for a window of another application (your case) you can't do it as this is the standard behaviour.

Comment: Everything is clear, if for self application, then thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: You're welcome. But consider that in Stackoverflow thank you should be translated with upvote and/or acceptance of the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this requires a reputation >= 15 :(

Comment: @nezlooy upvoting requires 15 rep but you can accept an answer (using the tick mark) with less.